# How else am I supposed to solve this(Google-GRR)?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, computer-forensics

https://github.com/google/grr/tree/master/api_client/python

I followed this link because I wanted to access the grr installation environment with python in another environment and remove the data.

However, `grr-response-proto==3.4.6post8` says that this version does not exist. What should I do?

```
(.venv) python % pip install --editable . 
Obtaining file:///Users/plitoo/Desktop/every_grr/grr/api_client/python
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of grr-api-client to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement grr-response-proto==3.4.6post8 (from grr-api-client) (from versions: 3.2.1.post4, 3.2.1.post7, 3.2.2.post0, 3.2.3.post0, 3.2.3.post1, 3.2.3.post2, 3.2.4.post0, 3.2.4.post2, 3.2.4.post3, 3.2.4.post4, 3.2.4.post5, 3.2.4.post6, 3.2.4.post9, 3.3.0.post0, 3.3.0.post2, 3.3.0.post3, 3.3.0.post4, 3.3.0.post8, 3.4.0.post0, 3.4.0.post1, 3.4.2.post0, 3.4.2.post1, 3.4.2.post3, 3.4.2.post4, 3.4.3.post1, 3.4.5.post1, 3.4.6.post0, 3.4.6.post7)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for grr-response-proto==3.4.6post8
```

https://pypi.org/project/grr-response-proto/
This is grr-response-proto 3.4.6.post7
Do I need to develop a new one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.